# Embedding of a finite group in a simple group

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group of order $n$. It is easy to follow that $G$ can be embed into $S_n$ and then $A_{n+2}$.

**Question :** What is the smallest size simple group in which any group can be embeded?

Comment: You mean as a function of $n$?

Comment: @ Captain Lama Yes

Comment: It depends on the group $G$ as well as its order $n$, so there is no answer. I expect you need to provide more information.

Comment: @Derek Holt Ok. Are there results for p-groups, solvable groups etc. I am only interested in non-abelain groups.

Comment: @DerekHolt No, the question does have an answer (although I don't know what it is of course). Since there are only finitely many groups up to isomorphism of a given size, for each $n$ there is indeed some least $k$ such that every group of order $n$ can be embedded into a simple group of order $k$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber  Yes, perhaps, but you have reworded the question to make its meaning clear. It could also be interpreted as "What is the size of the smallest simple group such that every group of order $n$ can be embedded in that group?" which could conceivably have a different answer.

Comment: @DerekHolt But under that interpretation too the question has a well-defined answer. Arguably it's unclear, but I don't agree with your original comment.

Comment: This function is highly irregular and almost certainly does not have any "nice" expression.

Comment: What is the upper bound then?

Comment: I think this question is extremely difficult. Is there a polynomial bound, or even a simply exponential bound? I have no idea. Even if you restrict attention to cyclic groups it is not completely trivial. I think the question in that case is similar to finding the smallest prime power $q$ such that $q \equiv \pm 1 \bmod n$, with a view to embedding the group in ${\rm PSL}(2,q)$.